# UTF-8 to UTF-16 in perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I want to convert an UTF-8 string to an UTF-16BE string in the hex notation.

As an example, let's say I have the string "C'est-à-dire que ça c'est l'été."

```perl
say sprintf("%vX", $string);  # 43.27.65.73.74.2D.E0.2D...
```

It should be converted to

```
00430027006500730074002d00e0002d...
```

I'm using

```
use Encode qw(decode encode); 
use feature 'unicode_strings' ;
```

Up to now, I was not successful using "encode" and "unpack".

What is the right way to go?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as [your question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1586694/utf-8-to-utf-16-in-perl). While I myself recommended that you post it on stackoverflow.com instead I've explicitly said that you should: *"... provide what you've tried so far instead of just saying it was not successful and expecting others to provide the full code for your problem."*.  So please edit your question to provide what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your string isn't encoded using UTF-8 as you claim. "`à`" (U+E0) encoded using UTF-8 would be `C3 A0`, but you have `E0`. I'm guessing you have decoded text aka a string of Unicode Code Points. (That would be a good thing. You normally want to work with decoded text.)

To convert decoded text into UTF-16be, you can use

```perl
use Encode qw( encode );
my $s_utf16be = encode("UTF-16be", $s_ucp);
# "\x00\x43\x00\x27\x00\x65\x00\x73\x00\x74\x00\x2d\x00\xe0\x00\x2d..."
```

---

But you don't want UTF-16be; you want the hex representation of the UTF-16be encoding of the string.

```perl
my $s_utf16be_hex = unpack("H*", $s_utf16be);
# "00430027006500730074002d00e0002d..."
```

Comment: From your comment on the other answer, I think you have a string of UCP aka decoded text rather than UTF-8.

Comment: "say sprintf("%vX", $string) ;" results in 43.27.65.73.74.2D.E0.2D.64.69.72.65.20.71.75.65.20.E7.61.20.63.27.65.73.74.20.6C.27.E9.74.E9.2E but none of the two solutions give the expected result.

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted the UTF-16 encoding of the string, but another reading of the question shows that you wanted the ASCII-encoded hex representation of the UTF-16 encoding of the string. I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sprintf` and `ord`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use feature qw/say/;

my $string = "C'est-à-dire que ça c'est l'été.";

say join("", map { sprintf "%04x", ord $_ } split(//, $string));
```

outputs

```
00430027006500730074002d00e0002d00640069007200650020007100750065002000e700610020006300270065007300740020006c002700e9007400e9002e
```

Comment: This works in the basic multilingual plane but will fail with anything else.

Comment: The "sprintf and ord" solution worked as expected in the present case. Of course, we have to consider the limitations of UTF-16. A more general solution would be using UTF-32, when a constant length of the characters is necessary.